# Responsive text size

Tags: responsive-design

Is it possible to set font size so that the text fills the available space and then changes its size with the `p` element if the window is resized?

In my demo (*link rotten as of March 2015*) the text in paragraph two is set to fill the paragraph by trial and error and if the window is resized the text wraps.

Comment: I've once seen that work using Javascript, but it works very jittery, because the script needs to enlarge and shrink the text until it fits. I think I haven't seen a better solution, and I wouldn't know how it would work. The only way to make it work, is when the script knows the exact pixel sizes of each of the letters in the font, including corrections for kerning. If it knew that, it could calculate the text width without displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

[FitText](http://fittextjs.com) is just the ticket if you want to use it for a headline, not recommended for entire paragraphs though.

**EDIT**

> FitText seems to need adjusting to get a proper fit...

Sure, every case is different. Out of the box it does work well though, here's a demo with the default `$("#fittext1").fitText();` setting for the compressor and minor changes to the CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/mSt5Y/

Comment: I've looked at FitText but I don't think it will work for me. I need it for headlines that will be dynamically generated. FitText seems to need adjusting to get a proper fit.

Comment: In theory, CSS3 introduces the vw unit which should allow to make any size depend on the viewport width ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/mSt5Y/10/)). Unfortunately, it now works as expected only in Firefox. Webkit browsers and IE10 don't readjust the font size set in vw units after window resize.

Comment: Interesting possibility @IlyaStreltsyn , plus there is a polyfil which claims to extend vw unit support to most browsers including IE 5.5+ , vminpoly -- https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa, may I ask you to have a look at a responsive design related question here : http://tinyurl.com/nadfh2u ?